# OpenMP Runtime does not speedup

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to make parallel version of a function. However, after adding openmp operations program supposed to speed up when the number of thread increased. It didn't happen. Also I get different results(outputs) when I run the program. This is the code I use. I appriciate your help

```
void simulate(int m, int n, double delt, double eps, double x[], double   y[], double z[], int iter, double xn[], double yn[], double zn[])
{

    double zero = 0.0, one = 1.0, twopi = 6.2831853071795864769252866;
    int i, itest, j,divtest;
    double aux,auy,delt2,delt3,eps2,fx,fy,fz,ftx,fty,ftz,step;

    return if n<5
    if (n < 5) return;

    //initialization
    iter = 0;
    delt2 = 0.5*delt*delt;
    delt3 = delt2*delt2;
    eps2 = eps*eps;

    //initial distribution of points
    auy = zero;
    itest=n+1;
    j = n+2;
    fx = (double)(n);
    x[1] = zero;
    y[1] = zero;
    z[1] = one;

    #pragma omp parallel private(i) {
        #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
        for (i=2; i <= n; i++){ 
            step = (double)(i+i-j)/fx;
            auy = fmod(auy+3.6/sqrt(itest*(one-step*step)),twopi);
            aux = sin(auy);
            x[i] = aux*step;
            y[i] = aux*sin(acos(step));
            z[i] = cos(auy);
        }
    }
    // main iteration loop

    while(itest==1){
        iter=iter+1;
        itest=0;
        #pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(i,j){
            #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait 
            for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
                // total sum of force vectors
                fx=zero;
                fy=zero;
                fz=zero;

                #pragma omp for schedule(static) 
                    for (j=1; j<=n ; j++) {
                        if (j != i) {
                            aux=pow(x[i]-x[j],2.0)+pow(y[i]-y[j],2.0)+pow(z[i]-z[j],2.0);
                            aux=aux*sqrt(aux);
                            fx=fx+(x[i]-x[j])/aux;
                            fy=fy+(y[i]-y[j])/aux;
                            fz=fz+(z[i]-z[j])/aux;
                         }
                     }

                 // tangential component of force
                 aux=x[i]*fx+y[i]*fy+z[i]*fz;

                 ftx=fx-x[i]*aux;
                 fty=fy-y[i]*aux;
                 ftz=fz-z[i]*aux;

                 aux=ftx*ftx+fty*fty+ftz*ftz;

      #pragma omp flush(itest)
      if (aux > eps2) {
          itest=1;
          aux=sqrt(one-aux*delt3);
          xn[i]=x[i]*aux+ftx*delt2;
          yn[i]=y[i]*aux+fty*delt2;
          zn[i]=z[i]*aux+ftz*delt2;      
      }
  }

  #pragma omp for schedule(static)
  for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
      x[i]=xn[i];
      y[i]=yn[i];
      z[i]=zn[i];
  }
  }  

  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo don't get speedup because there are many data races. (The different threads try to write the same variable at the same time). These data races are also responsible for the output errors you are getting. *(Thanks to @High-Performace-Mark for pointing this out)*

To make it simple, I recommend you to start parallelizing **only** the most inner loop (j). There you see that the `aux`, `fx`, `fy` and `fz` variables are modified by the different threads.

For `aux`, you can tell that this is a private variable and the `f` vas you can express them as a reduction (they sum up all the values in the different iterations):

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(aux) reduction(+:fx,fy,fz)
for (j=1; j<=n ; j++) {
  if (j != i) {
    aux = pow(x[i]-x[j],2.0)+pow(y[i]-y[j],2.0)+pow(z[i]-z[j],2.0);
    aux *= sqrt(aux);
    fx += (x[i]-x[j])/aux;
    fy += (y[i]-y[j])/aux;
    fz += (z[i]-z[j])/aux;
  }
}
```